# How to store in a variable the name of the class that will be used in place of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

Trying to re-factor the code, I've created a base class where I've put all the common functionality. I'm stuck with this one delegate that I want to convert to a method.

```
 Func<LogImportTestArgs, IList<TranslationTask>> 
 getParserWithMocks = (args) =>
 {
         return TestParserWithMocks<MyGenericClass>(
                parserConstName: args.ParserConstName,
                logFileName: args.LogFileName,
                srcLocale: args.SrcLocale,
                tgtLocale: args.TgtLocale,
                tlType: args.TranslationType,
                ttype: args.TTtype,
                logMappingID: args.LogMappingID
      );
   };
```

Everything is straightforward except for the generic class that I don't know how to store in a variable. I've tried to store the name of the class as a string, but I'm getting the error when I replace `MyGenericClass` with a string.

```
protected IList<TranslationTask> getParserWithMocks(LogImportTestArgs args)
{
         return TestParserWithMocks<MyGenericClass>(
                parserConstName: args.ParserConstName,
                logFileName: args.LogFileName,
                srcLocale: args.SrcLocale,
                tgtLocale: args.TgtLocale,
                tlType: args.TranslationType,
                ttype: args.TTtype,
                logMappingID: args.LogMappingID
      );
   };
```

Is there a way to stoire the value of the generic class in a variable? Otherwise I'm gonna have to copy/paste the same method on every tests. I'd like to have a central place where I can modify this method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parameterize `MyGenericClass` there, you will need to make the function generic:

```
protected IList<TranslationTask> GetParserWithMocks<T> (LogImportTestArgs args)
{
    return TestParserWithMocks<T>(
        parserConstName: args.ParserConstName,
        logFileName: args.LogFileName,
        srcLocale: args.SrcLocale,
        tgtLocale: args.TgtLocale,
        tlType: args.TranslationType,
        ttype: args.TTtype,
        logMappingID: args.LogMappingID
    );
};
```

Then, when you call the function, you will need to pass in the generic type:

```
IList<TranslationTask> tasks = GetParserWithMocks<MyGenericClass>(args);
```

Comment: I got an error telling me that T was not boxed or some ... it's because I didn't add the same constraint that `TestParserWithMocks` has on T. I've place the same constraint, now it's fine. I learned some on generic method. Thank you.

Comment: @Richard77 Yes, if `TestParserWithMocks` has a constraint on its generic type parameter, then every type you use it with needs to satisfy that constraint. So to ensure that, you need to add the same constraint (or a stricter one) on the new method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand, but it seems like you want the method to be generic:

```
protected IList<TranslationTask> getParserWithMocks<T>(LogImportTestArgs args)
{
     return TestParserWithMocks<T>(
            parserConstName: args.ParserConstName,
            logFileName: args.LogFileName,
            srcLocale: args.SrcLocale,
            tgtLocale: args.TgtLocale,
            tlType: args.TranslationType,
            ttype: args.TTtype,
            logMappingID: args.LogMappingID
      );
   };
```